# Typescript: Decorate constructor public param?

Tags: typescript, decorator

Is there any way to decorate members using the constructor parameter `public` shorthand?

If I do:

```
class Test{
  constructor(
    @decorator public b
  ){ }
}
```

Then, this is the parameter that gets decorated, not the member. Here is the compiled result:

```
var Test = function () {
    function Test(b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    Test = __decorate([__param(0, decorator)], Test);
    return Test;
}();
```

So the only way I've found to make it work as I expect is:

```
class Test{
  @decorator b;
  constructor(b){
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

That produces:

```
var Test = function () {
    function Test(b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    __decorate([decorator], Test.prototype, 'b');
    return Test;
}();
```

I know it's not so bad but repeating 4 times the same variable name makes me sick when I have a lot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to decorate members using the constructor parameter public shorthand

No.